# ローカル通知プラグインがインストールできない

Tags: monaca

http://blog.asial.co.jp/1403?category_id=21
この通りにやってもうまく行きません。
まず、zipファイルをアップロードするとfailedとでます。URLでインストールしてもビルドが失敗します。どうすればいいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

同じようになっていましたが解決しました。

ファイルはZIPでアップロードできました。GitHubの右側のDownloadZIPからダウンロードしたものをアップしました。
・プラグインをZIPファイルからインストール（GitHubのURLのからのインポートはファイルの修正ができないのでNG)
・プラグインが足りていないのでインストール（ZIP）
cordova-plugin-device
cordova-plugin-android-support-v4
・cordova-plugin-android-support-v4の名前が違うので設定ファイルの記述を変更

詳細は下記に記載してみましたのでご参考になれば。
http://qiita.com/hironaito/items/b0bb0a3de3ba82fc8895